# ADFS/SAML2.0 - How to set Claim Rules through Federation Metadata?

Tags: active-directory, saml, saml-2.0, adfs

I'm trying to implement a SAML 2.0 authentication against Windows ADFS for a web application. So far I succeeded in authenticating and getting what I need from ADFS by manually configuring the Relying Party Trust and the assigned Claim Rules.

Now I want to provide federation metadata for my application to make it easier to set up the required stuff in ADFS. However I can't figure out how to pass the required Claim Rules in that metadata.

Here's what I have so far:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<EntityDescriptor xmlns="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:metadata" xmlns:saml="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion" xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#" entityID="dokuwiki-entity" validUntil="2015-03-24T20:30:16Z">
  <SPSSODescriptor protocolSupportEnumeration="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:protocol" WantAssertionsSigned="true">
    <NameIDFormat>urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:nameid-format:transient</NameIDFormat>
    <NameIDFormat>urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:nameid-format:persistent</NameIDFormat>
    <AssertionConsumerService index="1" isDefault="true" Binding="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-POST" Location="https://perd.cosmo/dw-2014-01-13/doku.php?id=start"/>

    <AttributeConsumingService index="1">
      <ServiceName xml:lang="en">DokuWiki</ServiceName>
      <RequestedAttribute isRequired="true" Name="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/emailaddress" NameFormat="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:attrname-format:uri" FriendlyName="E-Mail-Adresse" />
    </AttributeConsumingService>
  </SPSSODescriptor>
  <Organization>
    <OrganizationName xml:lang="en">DokuWiki</OrganizationName>
    <OrganizationDisplayName xml:lang="en">DokuWiki</OrganizationDisplayName>
    <OrganizationURL xml:lang="en">https://www.dokuwiki.org</OrganizationURL>
  </Organization>
</EntityDescriptor>
```

From what I understand the `RequestedAttribute` should tell the ADFS to send me the user's E-Mail address upon authentication. Unfortunately after using this metadata to set up the Relying Party Trust no Claim Rules are set up.

Question: Is it possible to set up Claim Rules through metadata or has this always to be done manually? If it is possible where do I find the appropriate documentation?

Comment: did you get the solution on this? we are having same problem here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to setup the claimsrules manually (or through powershell). ADFS does not look at that part of the metadata.

Comment: Ah too bad but I feared as much when I couldn't find any documentation on it.

Comment: @paullem any reference mentioning that "ADFS doesn't support claimrules" will help