# Include required claims in RP metadata using spring-security-saml

Tags: spring, spring-security, adfs, spring-saml

Is there a way to include required claims in a relying party's metadata response using spring-security-saml?

Ideally I would like to provide a federation metadata URL to various IdPs which also specifies what claim types we require as the RP (i.e. email address, given name, surname etc). I am currently testing with ADFS as an Identity provider. When adding a relying party trust with the wizard using the RP metadata URL, most of the information is pre-filled except the "Accepted Claims" tab.

[image: Microsoft ADFS "Add Relying Party Trust Wizard]

I've tried to manually modify the metadata xml (as specified in [the docs](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security-saml/docs/current/reference/html/configuration-metadata.html#configuration-metadata-sp-import)) to include ClaimTypesRequired or ClaimTypesRequested elements within RoleDescriptor, though I'm not sure what to add... I'd also prefer to stick with the auto-generated metadata if possible.

Is my understanding of the RP metadata URL correct? Or would I be better providing IdPs with the URL and then tell them to add extra claims.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no out-of-the-box support for requested claims in auto generated Spring SAML metadata. But you can extend the [MetadataGenerator class](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security-saml/blob/master/core/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/saml/metadata/MetadataGenerator.java) to export the additional data as you require.

Answer (score 4):

Thanks to Vladimír's suggestion I extended MetadataGenerator class to add the AttributeConsumingService and RequestedAttribute elements as follows. I'm posting it here just in case it helps anyone.

```java
public class MySAMLMetadataGenerator extends MetadataGenerator
{
   @Override
   protected SPSSODescriptor buildSPSSODescriptor(String entityBaseURL, String entityAlias, boolean requestSigned, boolean wantAssertionSigned, Collection<String> includedNameID)
   {
      SPSSODescriptor descriptor = super.buildSPSSODescriptor(entityBaseURL, entityAlias, requestSigned, wantAssertionSigned, includedNameID);
      descriptor.getAttributeConsumingServices().add(generateConsumingService());
      return descriptor;
   }

   private AttributeConsumingService generateConsumingService()
   {
      SAMLObjectBuilder<AttributeConsumingService> builder = (SAMLObjectBuilder<AttributeConsumingService>) builderFactory.getBuilder(AttributeConsumingService.DEFAULT_ELEMENT_NAME);
      AttributeConsumingService service = builder.buildObject();

      SAMLObjectBuilder<ServiceName> builder2 = (SAMLObjectBuilder<ServiceName>) builderFactory.getBuilder(ServiceName.DEFAULT_ELEMENT_NAME);
      ServiceName serviceName = builder2.buildObject();
      serviceName.setName(new LocalizedString("application name", "en"));
      service.getNames().add(serviceName);

      SAMLObjectBuilder<ServiceDescription> builder3 = (SAMLObjectBuilder<ServiceDescription>) builderFactory.getBuilder(ServiceDescription.DEFAULT_ELEMENT_NAME);
      ServiceDescription serviceDescription = builder3.buildObject();
      serviceDescription.setDescription(new LocalizedString("Application description", "en"));
      service.getDescriptions().add(serviceDescription);

      SAMLObjectBuilder<RequestedAttribute> builder4 = (SAMLObjectBuilder<RequestedAttribute>) builderFactory.getBuilder(RequestedAttribute.DEFAULT_ELEMENT_NAME);
      RequestedAttribute nameId = builder4.buildObject();
      nameId.setIsRequired(true);
      nameId.setFriendlyName("Name ID");
      nameId.setName("http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/nameidentifier");
      nameId.setNameFormat("urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:attrname-format:uri");
      service.getRequestAttributes().add(nameId);

      RequestedAttribute email = builder4.buildObject();
      email.setIsRequired(true);
      email.setFriendlyName("E-Mail Address");
      email.setName("http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/emailaddress");
      email.setNameFormat("urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:attrname-format:uri");
      service.getRequestAttributes().add(email);

      RequestedAttribute givenName = builder4.buildObject();
      givenName.setIsRequired(true);
      givenName.setFriendlyName("Given Name");
      givenName.setName("http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/givenname");
      givenName.setNameFormat("urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:attrname-format:uri");
      service.getRequestAttributes().add(givenName);

      RequestedAttribute surname = builder4.buildObject();
      //surname.setIsRequired(true);
      surname.setFriendlyName("Surname");
      surname.setName("http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/surname");
      surname.setNameFormat("urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:attrname-format:uri");
      service.getRequestAttributes().add(surname);

      service.setIndex(1);

      return service;
   }
}
```

Unfortunately, Microsoft ADFS server [doesn't seem to support](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27926106/adfs-saml2-0-how-to-set-claim-rules-through-federation-metadata) these attributes for automatically setting claims. So don't bother wasting your time trying to get it working like I did!